# Retrieving Query Parameters inside a Component

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a HTML template with following element.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/final', {issue_id: 2356254}]">SUBMIT</a>
```

Clicking on this hyperlink will generate a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/final;issue_id=2356254
```

I'm trying to access this query parameter inside my component's constructor.

```
export class FinalComponent {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
        this.issueId = route.params._value.issue_id;
        console.log(this.issueId);
    }
}
```

This works so far but I know this isn't the correct method. What is the proper way to access query parameters inside an Angular 2 Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ActivatedRoute` is a good start.
You can subscribe to `params` property since it is a `Observable`:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    // access route params
    console.log(params['id']);
  });
}
```

---

*Sample on GitHub*

https://github.com/Angular2Buch/book-monkey2/blob/master/src/app/book-monkey/iteration-4/http/book-details/book-details.component.ts#L23

**route.snapshot**

If you are not interested in changes of the parameter you can simply use `this.route.snapshot.params`. So you do not have to handle with Observables.

*Sample*

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  let id = route.snapshot.params['id];
}
```

Comment: It worked! I've gone through the Angular documentation and found this code. 

this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
this.issueId = +params['issue_id'];
});

but I think your approach is much better.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get: aot/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts(45,30): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: @jjj Have you further information to this issue? A code sample or something like that?